# clumsy comprehension cleanup

Tags: python, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I have a nested loop that blends traditional for loops with list comprehensions:

```
dct = {}
for row in pat_mat:
    l = [float(x) for x in row[1:]]
    dct[row[0]] = l
```

How can I aggregate this into a nested list and dictionary comprehension?  Do you even think that will change the performance or readability of the code? Should I just leave it alone?

Here is the input:

```
pat_mat = [['A1BG', '3.59934160035066', '9.01032836656166', '7.49267439718532', '6.41276289887381'], ['A1CF', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['A2BP1', '3.06579631517157', '5.18615584800032', '3.18689667390982', '2.61953039353937']]
```

And the desired output:

```
dict = {'A1CF': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 'A2BP1': [3.06579631517157, 5.18615584800032, 3.18689667390982, 2.61953039353937], 'A1BG': [3.59934160035066, 9.01032836656166, 7.49267439718532, 6.41276289887381]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like -

```
dct = {row[0]:[float(x) for x in row[1:]] for row in pat_mat}
```

Also if the usage of dict in your code is not example , you should not name the variable dict, as it would override the built in function dict.

I think comprehensions are a little faster than their for-loop counterparts.

Comment: I realized the dict confusion as soon as I ran it, and changed it accordingly. And yes it worked!